# Convert HTML page to site core template

Tags: html, content-management-system, sitecore

Actually I'm  working on project where I need to convert a HTML website into Sitecore (CMS) template.

I'm really new to the Sitecore and I'm going through couple of docs but I'm sure how to proceed with any help would be very much appreciated..

Comment: It depends on what the page is doing, and how flexible the template engine is.  Ultimately, this question is a fair bit too broad to be answered reasonably, since experience and engine limitations vary depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can review high-level details on Launch Sitecore:

[Getting Started with Presentation Elements](http://launchsitecore.net/Articles/CMS/Build-My-First-Site/Presentation-Overview.aspx)

Comment: link in the answer redirects to a 404 not found page.